# How do I select columns from a Spark dataframe when I also need to use withColumnRenamed?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of

```python
df = df.select("employee_id", "employee_name", "employee_address")
```

I need to rename the first two fields, but also still select the third field. So I thought this would work, but this appears to only select `employee_address`.

```python
df = (df.withColumnRenamed("employee_id", "empId")
        .withColumnRenamed("employee_name", "empName")
        .select("employee_address")
)
```

How do I properly rename the first two fields while also selecting the third field?

I tried a mix of `withColumn` usages, but that doesn't work. Do I have to use a select on all three fields?

Comment: Keep in mind that  you could also do `select("*")` if  you wanted to select all of the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `alias` command:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

df = df.select(
    func.col("employee_id").alias("empId"), 
    func.col("employee_name").alias("empName"), 
    func.col("employee_address")
)
```

Comment: How would you go about doing that with also a `withColumn` function? Where I have to include a null field like `.withColumn('employee_birthdate', func.lit(None).cast(StringType()))` Any clean way to do that? Kinda looks ugly with the way I did it, but I can't think of any better way

Comment: You wouldn't need the `withColumn` you can just add another column to the `select` statement: `func.lit(None).cast(StringType()).alias("employee_address")` that will add a fourth column named `employee_address` that will contain all `null` values.